# Is this proof solvable? Doubt about natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am learning logic and I found a difficult exercise. I have been exercising for three days and I start to get overwhelmed. I would like some help, to learn from my mistake... I think not to plan things well.

Premises: $P \to T, S \to \lnot R, P \wedge (Q \vee R)$

Conclusion: $T \wedge (S \to Q)$

As the conclusion is conjunction I think it may be helpful to try to get each of the individual sets separately. I got $T$, the problem is the rest.

$S \to Q$ as an implication and I think it may be helpful to start with a sub-production headed by the background of the implication and try to get as far as possible within the scope of that sub-deduction... But I feel like I don't have enough to extract things.

Thinking about what to do I got this, but I think it's not useful:

```
R           A
-------------
      S     A
      -------
      ¬R    E->
  ¬S  I¬
R->¬S

Q           A
-------------
      S     A
      -------
      Q    it
  S->Q
Q->(S->Q)
```

I appreciate the possible help, I want to move forward understanding everything possible. :( Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.

Comment: Applying the rule E^ to get P with premise P^(QvR), and get T in the first premise with rule E->.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make no attempt to duplicate the tablature, so I describe the argument.

- From $P \wedge (Q \vee R)$, obtain $Q \vee R$.
- $Q \vee R = R \vee Q$ is equivalent to $\neg R \implies Q$.
- $S \implies \neg R$ is given.  By syllogism with the previous, $S \implies Q$, the clause you are seeking.

Comment: why Q∨R=R∨Q is equivalent to ¬R⟹Q?

Comment: This is typically the definition of [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).  Alternatively, condition on $\neg R$.  From $Q \vee R$ conclude $Q$.  Thereby obtain $\neg R \implies Q$.

Comment: Sorry, I have to solve it with the basic rules and I don't understand very well how the equivalence fits

Comment: Ok, I think I understand you. I need to get the premise to apply the rule, I'm going to check...

Comment: Your name is familiar :-):-). It is bad 0 score.

Comment: @Sebastiano : Eh.  0 scores happen.  Weirder is *accepted* 0 scores...

Comment: I prefer the scores :-) just for the time and patience that has been dedicated.

Comment: If you don't understand why $R \lor Q$ is the same as $\neg R \implies Q$ just write down the two truth tables.

Comment: Hi @Zeno, I haven't yet reached that part of the logic agenda but I'll check, thanks.

Comment: The usual natural deduction proof of $Q \vee R, \lnot R \vdash Q$ would use ${\vee}E$ on $Q \vee R$.  In the first case $Q$, you can directly conclude $Q$.  In the second case $R$, you can combine $R$ and $\lnot R$ using ${\lnot}E$ to get $\bot$, and then ${\bot}E$ (a.k.a. ex falso quodlibet) to conclude $Q$ in that case as well.